# Using user defined variables in the path of a results file in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to write a results CSV file in JMeter which contains a variable in path of the file I write.

E.g.

```
C:\\Users\\User1\\test-results\\${output}.csv
```

But I only seem to be able to use predefined variables like `${__time(ddMMyyHHmmss)}`

Is there a way to use user defined variables in the path? I have successfully done this to find input files by defining the variable in the test plan node as a User Defined Variable.

Comment: When is output variable defined ? at startup ?

Comment: @PMDUBIK-INGENIERIE It should be, but I'm not certain on the order of processing jmeter follows, my concern is user variables can never be defined before the output path of a results file is final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to use user defined variable in the path of result file using JMeter 2.9. REPORT is a user defined variable with value REPORT. It gives me file named REPORT.csv

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In JMeter 3.1(?) (or Windows?) a double slash is required in the path.

I have used the following successfully:

- `c:\\jmeter\\results\\${testId}\MyReport.csv`
- `c:\\jmeter\\results\\${testId}\MyReport.csv`
- `c:\\jmeter\\results\\${__time(yyyyMMddHHmm)}\MyReport.csv`
- `c:\\jmeter\\results\\${__time(yyyyMMddHHmm)}.csv`

`${testId}` is a User Defined Variable configured in the Test Plan and set to `${__time(yyyyMMddHHmm)}`

[image: User defined variable]

[image: Double slash in file name]